# C# String Array Replace Last Element

Tags: c#, arrays, string, replace

i have a String Array which comes from a splitted String

```
string[] newName= oldName.Split('\\');

newName.Last().Replace(newName.Last(), handover);
```

Why doesnt this replaces my last element in the Array?

last() comes from using linq

regards

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Calling `string.Replace` doesn't alter the existing string - strings are immutable.

Instead, it returns a *new* string, with the appropriate replacements. However, you're not using the return value, so it's basically a no-op.

You need to change the array element itself to refer to a different string. Something like this:

```
newName[newName.Length - 1] = handover;
```

Comment: Thx that worked fine. Never mentioned that its adding a new string there. Should have to read the manual;) replace ...

Answer (score 8):

Also, starting with **.NET Core 3.0** (and **.NET Standard 2.1**) you can use `Index` type to get/set array elements (like strings) from the end.
See example below:

```cs
newName[^1] = handover;
```

See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes) for additional info